# How can I link a subroutine to Autodyn?

Tags: linker, subroutine

I want to model reinforced concrete structures in Autodyn v6.1 under blast loading. So I am writting an user subroutine to model concrete with modified properties but I cann't link writed subroutine to Autodyn. So I am trying to find the solution 
or find some references/websites that can help me.

Comment: not even close to enough specific information to enable someone to answer

Comment: language? platform? what is autodyn?

Comment: you just take the subroutine, and you link it.

Comment: I am guessing Morteza refers to this http://www.ansys.com/services/ts-courses-detail.asp?TRAINING_ID=151

Answer (score 0):

If i am guessing correctly, and you refer to [Ansys Autodyn](http://www.ansys.com/services/ts-courses-detail.asp?TRAINING_ID=151) subroutine writing,

- [Programmers manual for Ansys Release 11.0](http://www1.ansys.com/customer/content/documentation/110/ansys/aprog110.pdf) PDF link
- [Compiling UPFs](http://www.scribd.com/doc/12313994/CompilingUPFs)

Comment: Thank You very much, your are so kind.

You are right but I Did what you said and when I wanted to relink a subroutine to Ansys, I faced with this error:
"LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file “ANSYS.exe” 
NMAKE: fatal error U1077: ‘link’ : return code ‘0x450’ 
Stop. "

I think it is because of ANSYS memory setting but I cannot solve this problem with modifying ANSYS Configuration.
Also i cannot find same user subroutines (in current Ansys directory) which I am using them in Autodyn v6.1. 
Do you have any idea about Autodyn v6.1?
 
Thank You in advance.

Comment: @Morteza, no I am not acquainted with Autodyn. I posted these links to (a) point you to them if you did not already know, and (b) to give anyone else who has more info, a starter.